# how to redirect current page to other page

Tags: php

I want to redirect current page to other page
i use this code but its not working

```
if($abc=="doc" || $abc=="docx" || $abc=="rtf")
        {
            header("Location: abc.php");
           }
```

AND

```
if($abc=="doc" || $abc=="docx" || $abc=="rtf")
    {
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=abc.php'>";

    }
```

Comment: Do you show any error messages ?

Comment: I think that `$abc` is not what are you expecting.

Comment: What you get if you try "echo $abc;" ?

Comment: Probably you are trying to send Location header after some content has been sent, try using ob_start() at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 1):

header() should work. However, it must be the first output of your script. If anything is sent before, it will not be taken into account. Check that the php script doesn't echo anything. Even newlines before the initial

Comment: Yes, that means no html tags or spaces, nothing pushed by an `echo` or any `print_..` or any `var_dump...` commands. Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: @shakti singh 
i have expected value in $abc